# How to create a hexagon clippath on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use a hexagon profile picture, but I'm having trouble using clip path with flutter.

The CSS code for the hexagon is this:

```css
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
```

[image]

how can I do it on flutter?

Answer (score 4):

Let's use [ClipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) to get this shape and follow the `css` the way you did.
`50% 0%` mean `(x, y)` and also same for`lineTo(x,y)` and `moveTo`.

```dart
class HexagonClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path
      ..moveTo(size.width / 2, 0) // moving to topCenter 1st, then draw the path
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * .25)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * .75)
      ..lineTo(size.width * .5, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * .75)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * .25)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
  ClipPath(
            clipper: HexagonClipper(),
            child: Container(
              width: 100, /// controll the size and color
              height: 110,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          )
```

**Result**

[image]

learn more about [ClipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; void main() => runApp(MyApp()); class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return MaterialApp( title: 'Hexagon', theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue, ), home: MyHomePage(title: 'Hexagon'), ); } } class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget { MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key); final String title; @override _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(); } class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> { @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Scaffold( body: Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0), child: ClipPath( child: Container( color: Colors.amber, ), clipper: _MyClipper(), ), ), ); } } class _MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> { @override Path getClip(Size size) { final path = Path(); path.lineTo(0, 0); path.lineTo(size.width, 0); path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.8); path.lineTo(size.width * 0.8, size.height); path.lineTo(size.width * 0.2, size.height); path.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.8); path.lineTo(0, 0); path.close(); return path; } @override bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false; }
```

or you can use a package called

```
flutter_custom_clippers: ^2.0.0
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, and i wanted something like this https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/warehouse/v1.0/publiccontent/3fbea522-774b-4114-9499-ca145d9e27f9

Comment: @yan did you try the package

Comment: I'm using this package right now, tryng to resize the hexagon to use it as a profile pic